# How do I make sure my function works for my variable?

Tags: javascript, function, var

```
function numberToTime(num){
var d = 0, h = 0, m = 0;
var numToMinutes = num*60;
while(numToMinutes > 59){
    numToMinutes -= 60;
    h++;
    if(h > 23){
       h-= 24;
       d++;
    }
    m = numToMinutes;
}
if( d > 0){
    return d + " days " + h + " hours " + m +" minutes ";
}else{
    return h+":"+m;
}
```

This code was given to me by a very nice user here on Stack Overflow.
Since I am very new to programming, especially JavaScript I have no idea where to put my variable. I have a `var howLong = (0,1 * amount + 0,2 * time)` I want to convert it to hours and minutes with the code above, but I don't know how to tell the function it's about `var howLong`.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: numberToTime(howLong)

Answer (score 0):

May be like this?

```
var ndays = Math.floor(sec/86400);
var nhours = Math.floor((sec%86400)/3600);
var nminutes = Math.floor(((sec%86400)%3600)/60);
var nseconds = ((sec%86400)%3600)%60;
return ndays + " days " + nhours + " hours " + nminutes + " minutes " + nseconds + " seconds";
```